# Complex numbers in R vs. Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, complex-numbers

I observed the following phenomenon when using R and Matlab.

When I apply log to a negative number in R, I get the following error message:

> Warning message:
> In log(-1) : NaNs produced

However, when I apply log to a negative number in Matlab, I get e.g., the following complex numbers:

> log(-1): 0.0000 + 3.1416i

> log(-5): 1.6094 + 3.1416i

Is there any way to achieve the same behavior in R? Or is there anything in favor of the default option in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`log` gives you complex when you give it complex in the first place.

```r
log(-1+0i)
# [1] 0+3.141593i
log(-5+0i)
# [1] 1.609438+3.141593i
```

I don't know why it doesn't give an option to do this by default, but then again I don't work in complex numbers all the time.

If you want to do this programmatically, you can use `as.complex`:

```r
log(as.complex(-1))
# [1] 0+3.141593i
```

or even make a helper function simplify it for you:

```r
mylog <- function(x, ...) log(as.complex(x), ...)
mylog(-1)
# [1] 0+3.141593i
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the different approaches. I use log inside a loop, so it would be great to include this aspect only when needed, i.e., when the number inside the log function is negative. At least that is how it is handled in Matlab. For example, if x = 5, it doesn't use complex numbers, but if x = -5, it displays the result as a complex number.

Comment: Sure, but ... in R, if anything in a vector (and column of a frame) becomes `complex`, then everything is complex, see `c(0,0+0i)`.